# Pointer Array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Pointers are a difficult topic for sure, but I have come across this snippet and I just can't figure out what the `p[-1]` is:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main(void) { 
    int t[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }, *p = t; 

    p += 2; 
    p += p[-1]; 
    printf("%d",*p); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: First, you add 2 to the pointer p, so it will point to 2 addresses further than before (so it now points to the address of `t[2]`). Now you access one address before the one it is pointing to, resulting in it pointing to the address containing the `2` (or `t[1]`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Any time you see an expression like `a[b]` in C, you can mentally think that `*(a + b)` is happening.

So, it's just "the contents of the element before the one `p` is pointing at right now".

Since `p` is at `t + 2`, `p[-1]` refers to `t[2 + (-1)]` i.e. `t[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
p += p[-1];
```

can be written as

```
p = p + *(p-1);
```

At that point, `p` points to the 3rd element of the array (value `3`) and `*(p-1)` is `2`.

So, it's equivalent to

```
p = p+2;
```

and printing `*p` would print `5`.

Comment: Awesome guys, thanks! That was quick!
Now I feel a bit dumb! But thanks a million for the thorough explanations!